# Как можно отправить такой же запрос без selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

На сайте [Агентства недвижимости в России](http://www.orgpage.ru/rossiya/%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8/10/) после 10 страницы остается только кнопка "Показать еще", по нажатию которой происходит загрузка следующей партии данных.

Как можно отправить такой же запрос без selenium? Через requests (get)?

В XHR запросах видно,что генерится ссылка вида:

```
http://www.orgpage.ru/Rubricator/ajax/RubricatorRegionLevel2Next/?rubricId=10239&rubricLevel=3&excludeIdList=854606,1261295,1309657,1470394,1508288,1768143,2052408,2053148,2246867,2223543,33673,31619,398446,699045,2528123,859166,2502772,1551941,2512081,1594761,836426,33686,843403,5395581,1242936,936348,35094,2503025,5400737,2496162&countryId=1&count=30&offsetNum=
```

с уже указанными новыми ID (excludedList). 
Но вот как она формируется - не могу найти.

Answer (score 0):

Вот запрос для подгрузки данных методом get, только в конце цифру надо менять для получения следующих данных. Можно сразу по ней парсить, не переходя по страницам http://www.orgpage.ru/Rubricator/ajax/RubricatorRegionLevel2Next/?rubricId=10239&rubricLevel=3&excludeIdList=2513242,1544053,2531378,945115,921353,1548315,5353852,2052447,910883,332404,2563016,959336,2565588,2505572,925525,1374985,1847051,252714,2511188,2544542,2550868,2560884,662226,2504949,957595,1469054,834463,582825,34444,965119&countryId=1&count=30&offsetNum=1    Пример на питоне

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.orgpage.ru/Rubricator/ajax/RubricatorRegionLevel2Next/?rubricId=10239&rubricLevel=3&excludeIdList=854606,1261295,1309657,1470394,1508288,1768143,2052408,2053148,2246867,2223543,33673,31619,398446,699045,2528123,859166,2502772,1551941,2512081,1594761,836426,33686,843403,5395581,1242936,936348,35094,2503025,5400737,2496162&countryId=1&count=30&offsetNum=%s'

data = {}
status = ok
while status:
    page = requests.get(url % n)
    status = page.ok()
    temp = page.text
    # парсинг данных в temp
    data.update(temp)
```

Comment: Спасибо, 10 страниц я уже собрал, только данных там гораздо больше, и следующий набор данных после 10 страницы загружается не на новую страницу, а на эту же, кнопкой "Показать еще" в конце списка и вопрос - как загружать их

Comment: Может я вас не правильно понимаю, у меня каждый запрос post возвращает ответ в json с набором организаций. вам страница по сути не нужна чтобы собирать информацию, обрабатывайте только запросы. Какая вообще задача, что надо достать

Comment: а у Вас json возвращает читаемые данные? у меня просто все в unicode - u0435\u0441\u043a.

Comment: у меня тоже возвращает данные, но почему-то в не читаемом виде. вот тут можете посмотреть таблицу символов https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters и придумать как организовать замену в коде. Например u003c это по таблице из википедии U+003C, а обозначает символ <

Comment: Iriskin, все проще, json.loads(temp) уже преобразует все в нормальный вид, модуль json умеет декодировать escape